# Get Property Optimization when using loops

Tags: c#, optimization

If I use loops in the get of a property, does this mean every time I call get on the property, it executes the loop? For eg, below, if I call `CartViewModel.Total`, does this mean it executes the loop inside SubTotal and Discount?

```
public class CartViewModel
{
    public decimal SubTotal { get { return CartViewItems.Sum(c => c.Price); } }
    public decimal Discount { get { return CartViewItems.Sum(c => Total-SubTotal); } }
    public decimal Total { get { return SubTotal-Discount; } }

    public List<CartViewItem> CartViewItems { get; set; }
}

public class CartViewItem
{
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
public float DiscountPercent {get; set;}
    public decimal SubTotal { get { return Price*Quantity; } }

    public decimal Total
    {
        get
        {
            return Convert.ToDecimal(((float)Price * (1 - (DiscountPercent / 100))
                       * Quantity));
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to optimize this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, every time you call the property, it will execute the loop.

Properties are really just syntactic sugar over method calls. Very *nice* syntactic sugar, but only sugar.

You might want to change `CartViewModel` to avoid exposing the list directly - instead, keep the list private, give some appropriate methods to mutate it (e.g. `Add` and `Clear` methods), probably make it implement `IEnumerable<CartViewItem>` itself, and keep track of the subtotal and discount as the list is mutated. That's assuming that `CartViewItem` is immutable, of course...

Alternatively (as John suggested), just make it more obvious that you're actually doing work, changing the properties to `ComputeTotal()`, `ComputeDiscount()` and `ComputeSubTotal()` methods.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the "don't *do* that" approach.

Properties are meant for cases where the data being accessed are "almost like a field" in terms of performance and semantics. They are definitely *not* meant for cases where the property hides the fact that a more expensive operation is being performed.

Replace those properties with methods and see whether the calling code changes much. It will be clearer that you are doing something potentially expensive.

Depending on how often those are referenced, I might go further and inline the properties entirely. That might suggest some optimization in the callers.